# Oracle 12cR2 RAC - ORA-06508

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-12c, plsql, recompile

***Environment:***

- ***DB Version:*** Oracle Database 12cR2 EE on Exadata
- ***RAC:*** True
- ***Problem:*** ORA-06508 on procedure.

> One of our users had a DBA role privilege, we don't want such a big
> privilege to be defined anymore. When we revoke the DBA role privilege
> from this user, all procedures, packages and triggers became invalid.
> This was something we expected at that moment and we accepted it as
> normal. When we compiled all of them, there was no problem and we
> reassigned the DBA role privilege to this user in order to postpone
> this work until later.
>
> The problem starts from this point. We get an error when one of the
> procedures wants to run. But the error is not constantly getting, for
> example it was working correctly for the last 26 hours, but then it
> got the error. When we drop / create or compile, the problem is
> solved. However, the strange part is that when this problem occurs,
> the procedure and dependencies all seem to be valid. The error is as
> follows:
>
> Error raised in: PROCEDURE_NAME at line xxxx - ORA-06508: PL/SQL:
> could not find program unit being called

***Line-xxxx:***

```
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN ROLLBACK;
    R_CODE:= 400;
    R_MESSAGE:='Error raised in: '|| $$plsql_unit ||' at line ' || $$plsql_line || ' - '||sqlerrm;
```

I could not find a suitable solution for this scenario on Oracle Support or on dba.stackexchange and I am still researching. Anyone have a good idea?

Best Regards,

Comment: Who owns the code? Who's calling the code when it errors? Is it a Definer's Rights code? ( `AUTHID DEFINER` ) Is CBAC in uses? Why are you not logging your error stack before you toss it? Without the full error stack, I don't think we can help you. Check GitHub for loggers.

Comment: @MichaelKutz, owner and caller are same users.

Answer (score 0):

$$plsql_line contains the line where it appears, which is useless locating the cause of an exception. You're not the first falling for this, eg. [using-plsql-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710999/oracle-pl-sql-debug-procedure-using-plsql-line). Read the solution there, eg. using  DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK in your exception handling.

Answer (score -2):

Reason: The called stored procedure has been modified
solution:Recompile stored procedures

Comment: That's not the main issue, I already know the solution you mentioned. The main issue here is; why this error is received and permanent solution is found. We cannot continually recompile this procedure.